# Nothing displays on parsing JSON data

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, jsonparser

I am trying to parse `JSON` data from `https://newsapi.org` and display it on a `recyclerview` in an application. A sample opf the `JSON` data is given below :

```
 {
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 10,
"articles": [
{
"source": {
"id": "google-news",
"name": "Google News"
},
"author": "Kanga Kong",
"title": "Kim Jong Un Sends Right-Hand Man to U.S. for Pre-Summit Talks",
"description": "North Korean leader Kim Jong Un has dispatched one of his top aides to the U.S. for talks ahead of his planned summit with Donald Trump next month, according to a person familiar with the issue who asked not to be named because the trip isn’t public.",
"url": "https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-05-29/kim-jong-un-sends-aide-to-u-s-for-pre-summit-talks-yonhap-says",
"urlToImage": "https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/i7_b0Umv.ads/v0/1200x802.jpg",
"publishedAt": "2018-05-29T05:42:00+00:00"
},
```

The problem is that I am unable to fetch any of the data from the given `JSON` data. The code is given below :

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG="MainActivity";
private List<Model> modelList;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private CustomAdapter customAdapter;

String url="https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=google-news&apiKey=76351c3c06504e12a8c61428162dcf87";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,modelList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    new DownloadTask().execute(url);
}

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String result=null;
        StringBuilder response = null;
        //Integer result=0;
        try {
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection;

            try {
                URL url=new URL(strings[0]);
                urlConnection=(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                int statusCode=urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                if (statusCode==HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    response=new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line=br.readLine()) !=null) {
                        response.append(line);
                    }
                    parseResult(response.toString());
                    //result=1;
                } /*else {
                result=0;
            }*/
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (final Exception e){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        Log.d("ResultForParsing : ",String.valueOf(result));
        Log.d("ResponseForParsing : ",response.toString());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        JSONObject mJsonResponse;

        try {
            if (progressDialog!=null)
                progressDialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*if (integer==1){
            customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,modelList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed to fetch data",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/
        parseResult(result);
    }
}

private void parseResult(String result){
    try {
        JSONArray posts=new JSONArray(result);
        modelList=new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0;i<posts.length();i++){
            JSONObject post=posts.optJSONObject(i);
            Model item=new Model();
            item.setAuthor(post.optString("author"));
            item.setTitle(post.optString("title"));
            item.setDescription(post.optString("description"));

            modelList.add(item);
            Log.d("AuthorForJSON : ",post.optString("author"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here, I have used a `Log` statement to display if the connection is OK and it returns 1 which means the connection is established successfully.

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Model> model;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Model> model) {
    this.context = context;
    this.model = model;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
    View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
    ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //ViewHolder viewHolder=(ViewHolder)holder;
    Model current=model.get(position);
    holder.n_author.setText("Author : "+current.author);
    holder.n_description.setText(current.description);
    holder.n_title.setText(current.title);

    //Picasso.get().load(current.urltoimage).into(n_image);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null!=model?model.size():0);
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView n_title;
    TextView n_author;
    ImageView n_image;
    TextView n_description;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        n_title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
        n_author=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_author);
        n_image=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_image);
        n_description=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_description);
    }
}
}
```

**Model.java**

```
public class Model {

public String author;
public String title;
public String description;
public String url;
public String urltoimage;
public String published;

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getUrltoimage() {
    return urltoimage;
}

public void setUrltoimage(String urltoimage) {
    this.urltoimage = urltoimage;
}

public String getPublished() {
    return published;
}

public void setPublished(String published) {
    this.published = published;
}
}
```

Currently I am only interested in getting the `author` name, the `title` and the `description`.

**Logcat**

```
    05-29 12:59:15.052 9368-9528/com.example.pritom14.saveeverything I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
05-29 12:59:15.052 9368-9528/com.example.pritom14.saveeverything D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fa58d2780 sslWrite buf=0x7f8f8e8000 len=240 write_timeout_millis=0
    ssl=0x7fa58d2780 sslRead buf=0x7f8f8e8000 len=2048,timeo=0
05-29 12:59:15.377 9368-9528/com.example.pritom14.saveeverything D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fa58d2780 sslRead buf=0x7f8f8e8000 len=2048,timeo=0
05-29 12:59:15.378 9368-9528/com.example.pritom14.saveeverything D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fa58d2780 sslRead buf=0x7f8f8e8000 len=2048,timeo=0
05-29 12:59:15.379 9368-9528/com.example.pritom14.saveeverything D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fa58d2780 sslRead buf=0x7f8f8e8000 len=2048,timeo=0
05-29 12:59:15.394 9368-9528/com.example.pritom14.saveeverything W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"status":"ok","totalResults":10,"articles":[{"source":{"id":"google-news","name":"Google News"},"author":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/bbcnews","title":"Private search for MH370 formally ends","description":"The Malaysia Airlines plane with 239 people disappeared while flying to Beijing from Kuala Lumpur.","url":"http:\/\/www.bbc.com\/news\/world-asia-44285241","urlToImage":"https:\/\/ichef.bbci.co.uk\/news\/1024\/branded_news\/E54A\/production\/_101789685_mediaitem101789684.jpg","publishedAt":"2018-05-29T05:17:22+00:00"},{"source":{"id":"google-news","name":"Google News"},"author":"Analysis by Stephen Collinson, CNN","title":"Trump whips up immigration storm over children","description":"For President Donald Trump, every crisis in America's immigration system is an opportunity.","url":"https:\/\/www.cnn.com\/2018\/05\/29\/politics\/donald-trump-immigration-separated-children\/index.html","urlToImage":"https:\/\/cdn.cnn.com\/cnnnext\/dam\/assets\/180523143703-02-trump-immigration-rountable-05-23-2018-super-tease.jpg","publishedAt":"2018-05-29T05:02:57+00:00"},{"source":{"id":"google-news","name":"Google News"},"author":null,"title":"The Rockets' heartbreaking failure to launch","description":"Houston's stars thrived, Clint Capela emerged and all the pieces fell into place. But in the end, the Warriors and an untimely CP3 injury proved too much to overcome.","url":"http:\/\/www.espn.com\/nba\/story\/_\/id\/23634056\/the-houston-rockets-heartbreaking-failure-launch-nba","urlToImage":"http:\/\/a2.espncdn.com\/combiner\/i?img=%2Fphoto%2F2018%2F0528%2Fr377007_1296x729_16%2D9.jpg","publishedAt":"2018-05-29T04:44:35+00:00"},{"source":{"id":"google-news","name":"Google News"},"author":"Vivian Salama","title":"White House Halts New North Korea Sanctions in Mad Dash to Save Summit","description":"The U.S. decided to defer launching a major new sanctions push against North Korea, part of a flurry of weekend moves by both sides aimed at reviving a summit between President Trump and North Korea’s Kim Jong Un.","url":"https:\/\/www.wsj.com\/articles\/nations-race-to-save-korea-summit-1527547115","urlToImage":"https:\/\/images.wsj.net\/im-12257\/social","publishedAt":"2018-05-29T03:44:58+00:00"},{"source":{"id":"google-news","name":"Google News"},"author":"https:\/\/www.nytimes.com\/by\/matt-stevens","title":"TV Journalists Covering Storm Are Killed When Tree Crushes S.U.V. in North Carolina","description":"The news anchor and photojournalist for WYFF News 4 in Greenville, S.C., had been reporting on the effects of Subtropical Storm Alberto.","url":"https:\/\/www.nytimes.com\/2018\/05\/28\/us\/tv-news-crew-killed-falling-tree.html","urlToImage":"https:\/\/static01.nyt.com\/images\/2018\/05\/29\/us\/29WYFF\/29WYFF-facebookJumbo.jpg","publishedAt":"2018-05-29T03:13:51+00:00"},{"source":{"id":"google-news","name":"Google News"},"author":"Erik Ortiz, Tim Stelloh, Associated Press, Mary Murray, Matthew Vann","title":"Two journalists killed as Alberto makes landfall on Florida Panhandle","description":"Two journalists for NBC affiliate WYFF of Greenville, South Carolina, were killed when a tree fell on their car in North Carolina after Alberto made landfall.","url":"https:\/\/www.nbcnews.com\/news\/us-news\/storm-alberto-nearing-landfall-along-florida-panhandle-threatens-heavy-rains-n878021","urlToImage":"https:\/\/media3.s-nbcnews.com\/j\/newscms\/2018_22\/2446921\/180528-storm-alberto-florida-1059a-rs_356711a28e00435f2979771b572648ba.1200;630;7;70;5.JPG","publishedAt":"2018-05-29T02:32:29+00:00"},{"source":{"id":"google-news","name":"Google News"},"author":"Laurel Wamsley","title":"On Memorial Day, Trump Honors Fallen Soldiers; Draws Criticism Over Tweet","description":"\"They fought and bled and died so that America would forever remain safe and strong and free,\" Trump said at Arlington cemetery. Earlier, he drew criticism online for praise some found self-serving.","url":"https:\/\/www.npr.org\/sections\/thetwo-way\/2018\/05\/28\/614993465\/on-memorial-day-trump-honors-fal
05-29 12:59:15.395 9368-9528/com.example.pritom14.saveeverything W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
05-29 12:59:15.398 9368-9528/com.example.pritom14.saveeverything W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
05-29 12:59:15.399 9368-9528/com.example.pritom14.saveeverything W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
        at com.example.pritom14.saveeverything.MainActivity.parseResult(MainActivity.java:109)
        at com.example.pritom14.saveeverything.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:28)
05-29 12:59:15.400 9368-9528/com.example.pritom14.saveeverything W/System.err:     at com.example.pritom14.saveeverything.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:78)
        at com.example.pritom14.saveeverything.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:49)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
05-29 12:59:15.401 9368-9528/com.example.pritom14.saveeverything W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-29 12:59:15.401 9368-9528/com.example.pritom14.saveeverything D/ResultForParsing :: null
05-29 14:54:04.099 16044-16149/com.example.pritom14.saveeverything D/ResponseForParsing :: {"status":"ok","totalResults":10,"articles":[{"source":{"id":"google-news","name":"Google News"},"author".....
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Thank you

Comment: did you debugged your parseResult  ? What does it return ?

Comment: @Umair, yes as I have debugged the parseResult and it returns 1. I have updated my question and I have included the `logcat`

Comment: Your this 
`public String urltoimage;
public String published;` Keys is not matching from response try to change key as per your response and try this `public String urlToImage;
public String publishedAt;`

Comment: and try to add complete array in your array  ` Model modal= gson.fromJson(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), Model .class);    modelList.add(modal); `  Hope it works

Comment: @SandeepParish, I am not displaying the `image` and `publishedAt`. I am only displaying `author`, `description` and `title`. So, it won't make any difference if I change it to `urlToimage` or `publishedAt`

Comment: @PritomMazumdar you are doing it wrong first I don't know why you are returning integer in your doInbackground method. You should return String or JSon. 
And secondly by taking a look at your logs it is giving exception 
 org.json.JSONException: Value
 at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
 at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
 at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)

Comment: You are checking status with 200 try to check you get with response "ok"

Comment: @SandeepParish, I have checked with `HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK` and it still returns 1

Comment: @Umair, could you please help me in correcting the `return` statements. Like if I return String in `doInBackground` what should I return?

Comment: @PritomMazumdar let me take a look at your code.

Comment: @PritomMazumdar  Check my new Answer it works for you definatly.

Comment: @PritomMazumdar I have posted the answer just to give you the idea take a look at this and tell me if it worked or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by problem using `Volley` which is an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster.

First, in **`app/build.gradle`** file :

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

Second, I modified my **`MainActivity.java`** file :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG="MainActivity";
private List<Model> modelList;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;

String url="https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=google-news&apiKey=76351c3c06504e12a8c61428162dcf87";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    modelList=new ArrayList<>();
    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    parseJSON();
}

private void parseJSON(){
    JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("articles");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject article = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String news_author = article.getString("author");
                            String news_title = article.getString("title");
                            String news_descrip = article.getString("description");

                            modelList.add(new Model(news_author, news_title, news_descrip));
                        }

                        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, modelList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(request);
}
}
```

And that's it!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work definatily because you are getting json object in your result param.

```
private void parseResult(String result) {

        Log.e("result::>", result);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            if (jsonObject.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");
                modelList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject post = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                    Model item = new Model();
                    item.setAuthor(post.optString("author"));
                    item.setTitle(post.optString("title"));
                    item.setDescription(post.optString("description"));

                    modelList.add(item);
                    Log.d("AuthorForJSON : ", post.optString("author"));
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do something like this. First in your `doInBackground method` return a string instead of `integer`

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = null;
        try {

           HttpsURLConnection urlConnection;

        try {
            URL url=new URL(strings[0]);
            urlConnection=(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            int statusCode=urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (statusCode==200){
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder response=new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line=br.readLine()) !=null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Common.EXCEPTION_ERROR_MSG, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And then in your **OnPostExecute()**

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        JSONObject mJsonResponse;
        try {
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

          parseResult(result);
    }catch(Exception ex){
 }
}
```

and your **parseResult** method will be the same:

```
 private void parseResult(String result){
    try {
        JSONArray posts=new JSONArray(result);
        modelList=new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0;i<posts.length();i++){
            JSONObject post=posts.optJSONObject(i);
            Model item=new Model();
            item.setAuthor(post.optString("author"));
            item.setTitle(post.optString("title"));
            item.setDescription(post.optString("description"));

            modelList.add(item);
            Log.d("AuthorForJSON : ",post.optString("author"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, nothing displays and on the logcat `05-29 14:37:42.148 14200-14327/com.example.pritom14.saveeverything D/ResultForParsing :: null`

Comment: that means you are not getting the result from that url. add a break point where you are sending the request and then where you recieve the result and tell me what you are getting.

Comment: Ah!, I missed one statement from your answer. But now a whole new error shows up. In the method `parseResult()`, it is indicating that `JSONArray posts` is a null object and it displays this error : `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Well that's pretty straight forward, your result string is null. that's why it can't parse the required result.

Comment: So, what should I return in place of result so that it can parse

Comment: first you need to check what you are getting in the result. what your request is returning then we can move forward.

Comment: just tell me what you are getting in this:  return result; ?

Comment: I have updated the `logcat` as well as the `MainActivity`. As you were asking about the `return result`, I have used a `log` statement to see what it returns and it returns `null`, I have also used a `log` statement for checking the parameter passed to `parseResult()` function. It return the whole `JSON` data in `String` format

Comment: See your problem is with the data you are getting. It's null how will it parse it. Try to understand  that. If you want to check either your service is working or not. First run it on postman tool. and if it is running fine there then come to the code.

Comment: Okay, I will surely do that

Answer (score 0):

if you check your root JSON object, it contains author, title, and description inside articles array, so first to need to hold "article" Array in JSONArray and then use this array to fetch author, title and description field